# Is a Wine prefix similar to a entire installation of Windows?

Tags: wine, games

I cannot grasp the idea of what is a prefix:
some guy in r/leagueoflinux says that is better to make a separate prefix to install League of Legends, because LoL requires "some workarounds" from time to time, I suppose that those workarounds are DirectX or something like configurations, so I do what he says. I install LoL in that different prefix, that means that if I install LoL in the default prefix, it is going to let me do it without saying that is already another copy of the game installed like it was another OS? And what if I try to install more than one thing in the different prefix? It is totally separated from the default prefix?
Aside, I have seen commands to create prefixes, but not to delete them, that means that maybe the space required to make a prefix is insignificant?

Comment: i found this article that solves most of my questions:https://linuxconfig.org/using-wine-prefixes

Comment: it does not say how to delete a prefix. I have to uninstall the programs that are inside the prefix and that is all?

Comment: Delete the folder containing the prefix after uninstalling the programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each "prefix" is a separate, clean base.

Replace the word "prefix" with "folder" or "directory" if that makes it any easier to grasp.

Some applications need specific tweaks to the wine configuration to run well, or at all in some cases. So, you create a new "folder" and configuration to go with it for each application, so that they don't interfere with each other, as some tweaks are needed to make one applications function, they can break another.

This is where something like Playonlinux comes in, as it can be tedious at best to manage multiple prefix's and in some cases different versions of wine.

You are not duplicating wine installs in most cases, but it can happen, and depending on the application some version work better than others.

Try this, WINE is like your...hmm, "Wine Cellar", the applications are each installed into separate bottles, ie "prefix's", because you don't want to blend them and alter the flavor characteristics.

I hope that made some sense to more than just me.